# Rxjs filter observable with array of filters

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, rxjs, observable

I'm here because i have a problem for filtering with Rxjs.
I'm trying to filter an observable of products with an array of filters...

Let me explain, I would like to set the result of my filtering to filteredProducts.
For filtering i have to check, for each filter, if the product's filter array contains the name of the filter and if the products values array's contains filter id.

For the moment, the filter works but only with the last selected filter and i'd like to filter products list with all filters in my selectedFilters array

```
export class ProductsFilterComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    @Select(FiltersState.getAllFilters) filters$: Observable<any>;
    @Input() products$: Observable<Product[]>;
    filteredProducts$: Observable<Product[]>;
    public selectedFilters = [];

    constructor(
        private store: Store) { super(); }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.store.dispatch(new GetAllFilters());
    }

    private filterProducts() {
        this.filteredProducts$ = this.products$.pipe(
            map(
                productsArr => productsArr.filter(
                    p =>
                        p.filters.some(f => this.selectedFilters.some(([selectedF]) => selectedF === f.name.toLowerCase()) // Filter name
                            && f.values.some(value => this.selectedFilters.some(([, filterId]) => filterId === value)) // Filter id
                        )
                )
            )
        );
        this.filteredProducts$.subscribe(res => console.log('filtered:', res));
    }
}
```

Here's the structure of a product object
[image: Here's the structure of a product object]

Here's the structure of selectedFilters
[image]

A big thank you in advance :-).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change `selectedFilters` to [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) and use that with `products$` observable. There is [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) function which listens for latest values of multiple observables and returns an array

**Example**

```js
window.products$ = rxjs.of([
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "product 1",
        category: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'test'
        },
        filters: [
            {
                name: "test1",
                values: [1]
            }
        ],
        url: '/assets/test1.png'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "product 2",
        category: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'test'
        },
        filters: [
            {
                name: "test2",
                values: [2]
            }
        ],
        url: '/assets/test2.png'
    }
])
window.filteredProducts$ = null;
window.selectedFilters = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject([])

function filterProducts() {
    filteredProducts$ = rxjs.combineLatest(products$, selectedFilters)
        .pipe(
            rxjs.operators.map(
            ([products, filters]) => products.filter(
                product =>
                    product.filters.some(filter => filters.some(([filterName]) => filterName === filter.name.toLowerCase())
                        && filter.values.some(value => filters.some(([, filterId]) => filterId === value))
                    )
            )
        )
    );
    filteredProducts$.subscribe(res => console.log('filtered:', res));
}

filterProducts()
window.selectedFilters.next([...window.selectedFilters.value, ['test1', 1]]);
window.selectedFilters.next([...window.selectedFilters.value, ['test2', 2]]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Józef !
I'm trying to implement your solution in angular but i get differents error because selectedFilters is an array and i use different methods on it. I'm gonna continue to implement it and let you know :)

Comment: You have to change `selectedFilters` to BehaviorSubject as your data relies on its latest state. Otherwise app won't know whats going on

Comment: It's ok but it render the same result as at the start. It's ok when i selected only one filter but now i get more results when i add another filter. I think it took the last filter to make the filtering.
When i log my selectedFilters, i see all the selected filters.

Comment: You can check at the start if the filter array is empty and if so you can just return all products

Comment: I launch the function when i add or delete filter. It's ok when the array is empty.
The problem is when i have more than one filter in behaviourSubject's value. The function use only one filter and not all

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, but can be modified a bit.
For start, I would clean the predicate, you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) [`intersectionWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersectionWith) function to intersect two arrays with different values.
Also, you can use [`mergeAll`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeAll) operator to iterate filter by filter, which makes this look less nested.

Overall it should look something like this:

```js
products$
  .pipe(
    mergeAll(),
    filter(
      product =>
        _.intersectionWith(
          product.filters,
          selectedFilters,
          (filter, [name, id]) =>
            filter.name.toLowerCase() === name && filter.values.includes(id)
        ).length > 0
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

You can run the full example code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ncublb?devtoolsheight=60)

Comment: Thanks for your help and your explanations, Tal :).
With your method, i log each product who correspond to one filter but when i add another filter i get an error 'undefined is not a function'

Comment: If you could reproduce your error on stackblitz I will look into it

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it on Stackblitz but i post an answer with the error

Answer (score 0):

There's is the error i get. And the lines where there's the error.
[image]

[image]